# In Android, how to start new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I know this has been asked before, but I just can't get it to work.  I created 2 Activities:

My Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ToActivity.Class);
        myIntent.putExtra("key", itemValue); //Optional parameters
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

My Sub Activity

```
public class SubActivity extends Activity {
    setContentView(R.layout.sub_layout);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSub);
    title.setText("Sub Menu: "+intent.getStringExtra("key"));
}
```

My Manifist

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ToActivity"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any error in the Logcat ? Could you be more explicit on why this doesn't work ? BTW, ToActivity.Class will launch ToActivity, not SubActivity of course. I proposed and edit.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the relationship between ToActivity that is defined in the Manifist file and how it's used in the Activities file.

Comment: what's SubActivity?? what for it's used??? same class or different??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't added your two activity's in your manifest file.. you have mentioned different packages..

mention like this..

```
<activity  android:name=".MainActivity"/>
<activity  android:name=".SubActivity"/>
```

that to `ToActivity` is not defined..

Comment: This worked!  I just didn't understand the relationship between MainActivity, SubActivity, and ToActivity.